# How can I move an image using X and Y cordinates of a click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a function to my site that when a user clicks in a random location an image appears in said location.

This is my current code all within my `HTML`, Im guessing I have to use `xpos` and `ypos` as their outputs in some sort of position tag?

```js
  <script>
    function showCoords(event) {
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
      var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
      document.getElementById("xpos").innerHTML = x;
      document.getElementById("ypos").innerHTML = y;
    
    }
    </script>
```

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html onclick="showCoords(event)" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <body>
    
    <h2 >Click this heading to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer when it was clicked.</h2>
    
    <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places in the heading.</p>
    
    
     <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eed5cc775d5b7fa27c3d7f5/5eef73e7ad8dd5e992850fea_Video-Thumbnail.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" > 
    
     <p id="demo"></p>
     <p id="xpos"></p>
     <p id="ypos"></p>
    
    
     on
  
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: _appears in said location_ what mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using JS and applying styling and making the image `position` to `absolute` to that image according to clicked cords `x` and `y`

Click anywhere on the snippet screen to see the `img` appear / move there.

Run snippet below.

```js
function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
  document.getElementById("xpos").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("ypos").innerHTML = y;

  var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  image.style.display = '';
  image.style.position = 'absolute';
  image.style.left = x + 'px';
  image.style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="showCoords(event)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

<body>

  <h2>Click this heading to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer when it was clicked.</h2>

  <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places in the heading.</p>


  <img id="myImage" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eed5cc775d5b7fa27c3d7f5/5eef73e7ad8dd5e992850fea_Video-Thumbnail.png" alt="Girl in a jacket">

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="xpos"></p>
  <p id="ypos"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ri20 Glad to hear. Would you mind accepting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and up-vote as well. Thanks :)